# npm keeps installing globally

Tags: javascript, npm, npm-install

I'm using latest npm, on a mac. I've got a strange problem: if I want to install some package locally on a folder, I'm forced to `npm init` it. In other words, if I simply `npm install [package name]`, it will install globally (in my /User/npm-modules folder), and thus the onnly way to install locally is to init the folder. So basically, the opposite it should normally do. Why? Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, if you want to install package localy, you need to create package.json file. This is what npm init will do and then you can install packages

Comment: ah ok, I didn't know it was by design, it's not documented on the npm-install entry of the official docs. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

`npm init` creates `package.json` file in your current project directory. npm packages will install locally when you have `package.json` set up by using the command `npm i PACKAGE-NAME`.

Comment: npm packages?  That isn't a command.  Did you mean npm install ?

Comment: I just referred to npm packages.